# MySQL Error #1064 on WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Details

- Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.7
- MAMP Version 1.7.2
- PHP Version 5.3.4
- MySQL 5.0.41
- Table Type: MyISAM
- Encoding: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
- Collation: utf8_unicode_ci

Basic MySQL "INSERT" query:

```
$startMonth = $date->getMonth();
$startDay = $date->getDay();
$startYear = $date->getYear();
$startTime = $date->getTime();

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO todos 
                  VALUES (startMonth, startDay, startYear, startTime)
                  VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d)
                   WHERE todo = '%s'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($startMonth),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($startDay),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($startYear),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($startTime),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($todo));

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: " . $q . "<br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
```

Here is the mysql_error that prints out:

> A MySQL error has occurred.
>   Your Query:
> INSERT INTO todos SET startMonth = 6 AND startDay = 27 AND startYear = 2011 AND >startTime = 1309216538 WHERE todo = todo 2
>   Error: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE todo = todo 2' at line 1

I've tried it every possible way I can think of. From changing the query to "INSERT INTO todos SET startMonth..." etc.

I've encoded the `$todo` variable in every possible way imaginable (i.e. addslashes, magic_quotes_pgc (even though it's deprecated ...I was getting desperate), htmlentities, mysql_real_escape_string... everything I could find and/or think of).

Comment: Overwriting existing values means you need to use an UPDATE statement, not INSERT...

Comment: Your error is displaying `$q` but your query is stored in `$query`

Comment: `... AND >startTime` is a syntax error, on top of everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), you can't use a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement. You also have 2 `VALUES` clauses. It looks like your first `VALUES` clause is defining the fields you're inserting into as opposed to being values.

If you're trying to `INSERT`, than you'll want to do this:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO todos (todo, startMonth, startDay, startYear, startTime)
                  VALUES ('%s', %d, %d, %d, %d)",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($todo)
                  mysql_real_escape_string($startMonth),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($startDay),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($startYear),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($startTime));
```

Comment: What I wouldn't give to have a second pair of eyes around :). Thanks to all. You're fantastic! My first time on here... how do I mark this as "answered"?

Comment: @tchnchn - 15 minutes after you posted the question, you'll be able to accept the answer by click on the green checkmark to the left of my answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO todos SET startMonth = 6 AND startDay = 27 AND startYear = 2011 AND >startTime = 1309216538 WHERE todo = todo 2
```

should be

```
UPDATE todos SET startMonth = 6, startDay = 27, startYear = 2011 WHERE startTime = 1309216538 AND todo = 2;
```

You're confused with with the proper syntax for an update statement.  AND is a logical operator.  You need to use commas when assigning a value through your update statement. INSERT != UPDATE.

That, and there is some other crazy stuff going on with your statement.  Either way, the second statement should work as long as your naming/schema is correct

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two errors in `INSERT` that Francois explained, you are running one (`$query`) and printing another (`$q`):

```
$result = mysql_query($query)                                  --- $query is not 
or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: " . $q    --- same with $q
  . "<br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
```